# Default path to clone from, like CVSROOT?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, clone, cvs

A friend asked if it is possible to set the default place where users checkout Mercurial modules from? CVS has a the environment variable `CVSROOT`, which is used by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that directly matches the `CVSROOT` variable in Mercurial, so you won't find a `HGROOT` environment variable in [`hg help env`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#env).

But you can do something similar with the [schemes extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SchemesExtension). It lets you define new URL schemes that act as shortcuts for longer URLs. So if you often type:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/<something>
```

then you can load the extension and instead type

```
$ hg clone bb://<something>
```

The `bb://` scheme is a default scheme in the extension. These schemes work whereever you can give Mercurial a URL, so you can push/pull with them too.

You can add your own schemes with something like

```
[schemes]
x = /mnt/server/var/repos/
```

and then use `hg pull x://foo` to pull from your `/mnt/server/var/repos/foo` repository.

From a comment of yours, it's not clear if you're really after shorthands when you `hg pull`. They can be created by adding entries to the `[paths]` section, see [`hg help paths`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#env). If you add

```
[paths]
foo = somewhere
```

then you can run `hg pull foo` to pull from `somewhere`.